# BASH: Is there a way to automatically save recent lines to my bash history during a period of inactivity?

Tags: shell, scripting, history, bash

The `.bash_history` file is a life-save for many of us. Unfortunately, BASH only seems to save the commands of a session when that session is closed (via `exit`).

It's a tragedy, then, when all your commands from an important session are vaporized when a session is closed unexpectedly -- before it gets to archive all the commands with fancy syntax that took hours to get right....

This happens to me when I forget to close a SSH connection when leaving work, and it gets disconnected due to inactivity (`Write failed: broken pipe`), or when I restart my computer without closing my terminals manually, and so on.

**I would love to have my BASH commands archived after some interval -- say every 10 minutes -- so that if I do close a session, my commands will still be there.** This seems like something a lot of people might find useful.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

***Ideally....***

- The functionality would require no extra effort on the user's part once set up -- something he/she could add to `~/.bashrc`
- The user could change the backup interval
- It would avoid using temporary files, aliasing `bash`, or other "hacks"

*StackOverflow*-ers -- consider yourself challenged!

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623700/bash-history-is-lost-after-ssh-connection-is-reset-by-peer-how-to-save-the-his

Answer (score 12):

You can use `history` command with `-a` option:

```
history
-a     Append the ``new'' history lines  (history  lines  entered  since  the
       beginning of the current bash session) to the history file.
```

You can write each and every command to history file at once with a little help of `PROMPT_COMMAND` function:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND
If set, the value is executed as a command  prior  to  issuing  each  primary prompt.
```

So just put this into .bashrc

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

Comment: So what this does is archive any new commands entered since the last archival -- effectively each command will be archived upon successful completion of that command, right?

Comment: Yes, if by "successful completion" you mean that command was typed-in the command-line and enter was hit. If command had any sense that is another story, but it would be saved in .bash_history.

Comment: Can this be automated, perhaps by running some `cron`-like job in the background? If so, I'll mark the question as accepted!

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/463366/does-getting-disconnected-from-an-ssh-session-kill-your-programs/463375#463375) bash will (usually) receive a `SIGHUP` on disconnect.

Using `trap` we can write the history (lame as #*?! that bash doesn't do it by default though..):

```
function rescue_history {
    history -a
}
trap rescue_history SIGHUP
```

Put the above in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Created: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623700/bash-history-is-lost-after-ssh-connection-is-reset-by-peer-how-to-save-the-his.

Comment: This obviously cannot keep your history in case of system crash or power loss. I'd recommend using `PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` in your `.bashrc` instead.